# Left Outer Join not returning all records from primary table

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

When I do a left outer join, I expect to get all the records that the query would return prior to adding the joined table, but it is only returning records that match the joined table (i.e: no record for '092387' exists in table 'documentation', so I just want null returned for 'filename' field for that record.) What am I doing wrong?

```
mysql> select documentation_reference.ref_docnumber
            , documentation.filename 
      from documentation_reference 
      left outer join documentation on ref_docnumber=documentation.docnumber      
      where documentation_reference.docnumber='TP-036' 
      and documentation.status!=3;
+---------------+-----------------+
| ref_docnumber | filename        |
+---------------+-----------------+
| SOP-0042      | SOP-0042r39.pdf |
+---------------+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select ref_docnumber 
       from documentation_reference 
       where documentation_reference.docnumber='TP-036';
+----------------------+
| ref_docnumber        |
+----------------------+
| 092387               |
| 1100218B             |
| Applicable Item Spec |
| SOP-0042             |
+----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your where clause is converting the outer join back into an inner one.

The non matching rows preserved by the `outer join` will all have `NULL` values for `documentation.status` so your `documentation.status != 3` condition will filter these back out (The result of the expression `NULL !=3` is `unknown` not `true`).

To avoid this issue use

```
select documentation_reference.ref_docnumber,
       documentation.filename
from   documentation_reference
       left outer join documentation
         on ref_docnumber = documentation.docnumber
            and documentation.status != 3
where  documentation_reference.docnumber = 'TP-036'
```

Note that the `documentation.status != 3` predicate is moved into the `JOIN` condition.

Comment: Right... that was it. Thanks for your help - that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Check your  `documentation.status!=3` condition...it might  be the culprit..it is I think eliminating your expected records.

Usually to debug this issue run your query in parts, firstly run-

```
select documentation_reference.ref_docnumber, documentation.filename from documentation_reference left outer join documentation on ref_docnumber=documentation.docnumber
```

check the results and then run query with the where -

```
select documentation_reference.ref_docnumber, documentation.filename from documentation_reference left outer join documentation on ref_docnumber=documentation.docnumber
where  documentation_reference.docnumber = 'TP-036'
```

Check the results they should change once you add the final where condition -
`documentation.status!=3`

You should probably follow Martin's advice and run his code to get expected results.